# Script to get coordinates of selected polygons (country borders) - in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, polygon, coordinates

I'm new to qgis, I just need to retrieve from the selected polygons their coordinates list.

I want to use python's console with a script.
I'm using QGIS v3

This is a sample of my bare attempt to do so:
[image]

Comment: make sure you post all code and related error messages correctly formatted (**`{}`** button) so they are selectable for copy-paste etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [method family](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsGeometry.html#a5801ab30650e161147d28a2e7220d3d3) to export a *QgsGeometry* object's geometry representation into available formats [has changed](https://qgis.org/api/api_break.html) with QGIS 3.0 into `QgsGeometry.as[Format]()`, e.g.

```
for i, elem in enumerate (layer.selectedFeatures()):
  geom = elem.geometry()
  wkt = geom.asWkt()
  print("element: ", i, "wkt: ", wkt)
```